Quentin Tarantino in a movie having a monologue about the Death Star
I saw this movie some decades ago. I believe Tarantino had a small (cameo?) role.
Close to the beginning of the movie, there was like an outdoor party, and the character played by Tarantino had a monologue about the Rebels destroying the Death Star while it was still being built, and a lot of ordinary workers were on it helping to build it, and they all have perished when it was destroyed.

I believe you're referring to Clerks (1994). The characters discuss the Death Star and the contractors who were harmed.



Tarantino doesn't appear in that film, but it's likely you're misremembering him from the DVD extras. He and Robert Rodriguez are friends of Clerks Writer/Director Kevin Smith and they filmed a featurette for Clerks II (2006), which you may have seen on the same DVD.




The questioner's memory may also have been coloured by Tarantino's cameo in Sleep With Me (1994) where he explains what Top Gun is really about.
